# Internet speeds 300+ Mbps after bootup. Then next speed test is about half the speed

Tags: networking, internet, internet-connection, internet-speed

I have a Windows 10 machine that with the latest updates installed.
I noticed that after a reboot I can run an internet speed test using Ookla or any other online speed test and get about 300+ Mbps. However, subsequent speed tests show results that are about 1/2 the speed of the test after a fresh boot. This occurs on both the ethernet connection and any wifi card/adapter that is installed.

All my drivers are current etc.

[image]

[image]

What might be happening here and how might I fix this?
**Note that in Safe Mode with Networking the speeds are over 830Mbps. So I guess some software/driver or Windows settings is causing issues?**

Comment: We need more information about your setup.

Comment: @harrymc I've added more detail. Let me know what else may be needed. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using WiFi or Ethernet for the computer and router? For WiFi, do you have an extender or are you directly connected to the router?

Comment: I have a Zyxcell 2.5GB switch connected to the router via a 2.5GB LAN port. The computer is connected to one of the ports on the switch.

WiFi has no extenders. The computer is in line of sight about 30 feet away from router.

Other devices on the wireless network consistently get over 300Mbps speeds. So it's something with this particular computer.

I'll note that this wasn't an issue until about 2 or 3 weeks ago.

Comment: Has something changed in the environment of this computer, such as a new electrical appliance? Can you test this when booting in Safe Mode with Networking?

Comment: No new electrical appliance. In fact, it's six feet away from a device connected to the same network and it doesn't have this issue. I will try in Safe Mode with Networking. Thank you.

Comment: Safe Mode with Networking allows the network speed to be 830+Mbps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As booting in Safe Mode with Networking fixes the problem, this indicates
that some third-party application is responsible for this.

This can also be a third-party driver that is disabled in this mode,
so check you are using the latest driver for your network adapter
from the manufacturer. If that driver has the same problem,
delete the adapter from the Device Manager, together with its driver,
and let Windows use its own driver.

Otherwise, if this is caused by some installed application,
you may use the free tool
[Autoruns for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns)
to locate it.

This utility shows all programs configured to run during system boot or login
in its "Everything" tab.
You may turn off startup items with a click and return
them with another click. You may avoid listing Microsoft products by
using the menu *Options > Hide Microsoft Entries*,
*Hide Empty Locations* and *Hide Windows Entries*

I would suggest turning off startup entries in bunches,
drilling down to the startup program that causes this behavior.
Once identified, it might have some setting
that can avoid the problem, or can be uninstalled.

I would start with your security software, antivirus suite and similar,
then continue with any other browser- or internet-related products.

Comment: It's probably some shit I.T. put on the computer recently.